# CSS maintain original styles on elements added by a JS library

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a web application with a lot of `<div>` used for layout. Now I need to add some tables drown by a library. The issue is that the library creates a lot of `<div>` with their own style and depending on the position they collide with styles already in place for `<div>` in that position.

This is the (very) simplified html structure where `[myTableDataSource]` identify the element with the table.

```
<div id="id1">
    <div>
        <div myTableDataSource="xxx"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="id2">
        <div myTableDataSource="yyy"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="id3">
        <div>
            <div>
                <div myTableDataSource="zzz"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My idea is to avoid applying style on `<div>` that are descendant of `[myTableDataSource]`but... How can I do? Is there a selector to get all `<div>` element not descendand of a `[myTableDataSource]` attribute?

Please consider that I have a style for all `<div>` descendant of `#id1`, of `#id2`, `#id3` [...] and I can't change this, but only modify selector to avoid conflicts.

Comment: Are you saying you can or can't modify the html? If you give them classes then a `div` element without those classes won't be affected

Comment: you want to apply effect on only <div> not for those div which has <div myTableDataSource="..."> ?

Comment: @DarrenSweeney I can't modify the HTML code of `div` added by the library
@IQBALPASHA excluding only those `div` is trivial, the problem is excluding `div` that are their descendants

Answer (score 0):

What about using attributes and the `.not()` selector?

Something like this is a start:

```
#id1 div:not([myTableDataSource="xxx"]) {
  background: orange;
  padding: 30px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}

div[myTableDataSource="xxx"] {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: grey;
}
```

To ignore descendants (not tested):

```
#id1 div:not([myTableDataSource="xxx"]):not(div[myTableDataSource="xxx"] div){ ... }
```

Comment: this is working on div with `[myTableDataSource="xxx"]` attribute, not on their descendants

Comment: `div[myTableDataSource="xxx"] div { ... }` would work for descendants?

Comment: sure, but I don't have to style descendand, I have NOT to style descendant, so the issue is in `#id1 div:not([myTableDataSource="xxx"])` that should select all div except the ones descendant of `[myTableDataSource="xxx"]`